# Creating an executable exe file of a windows desktop application

Tags: c#, sql-server, localdb

if I used  my sql server express local DB in my windows desktop application and I built the installable/release version of the application, if I install it on another pc will the it be able to use the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to deploy the LocalDB installer as well - you can either do that by packaging the LocalDB.msi installer to your zip - or you can bundle it with your ClickOnce installer.

In your project's properties in Visual Studio select `Publish / Prerequisites / SQL Server Express LocalDB`.